# How can I embed schema.org markup in SVG?

Tags: svg, schema.org

I wish to add semantics to SVG files and would like to use schema.org terms. Does SVG have a syntax for doing this? My first attempt would be:

```
<svg:text xmlns:svg="xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="100" y="200"   
       html:itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       >Joe Soap</svg:text>
```

Will this be valid SVG and display in conformant tools? and will the schema.org markup be recognized by search engines?

Comment: 12 days on and no answer - It looks like their is no current standard - I shan't offer a bounty.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38775825/semantically-correct-way-to-add-a-copyright-notice-into-a-svg-file

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it, but I guess it should be possible to use [**RDFa**](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/), as SVG Tiny 1.2 [allows the attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-SVGTiny12-20081222/metadata.html#MetadataAttributes)

- `about`
- `content`
- `datatype`
- `property`
- `rel`
- `resource`
- `rev`
- `typeof`

(You could use the [`metadata` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-SVGTiny12-20081222/metadata.html#MetadataElement) with [RDF/XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/).)