# Semantically correct way to add a copyright notice into a svg file?

Tags: svg, metadata, copyright-display

I want to add a copyright notice in my svg files and it should be only "hidden" text and no watermark.
This is no real protection, because if you open a svg file with a text editor you can edit everything and delete the copyright. But I think this would be a simple and great way to show, who has made the file and a possible chance to find unlicensed graphics if there is some hidden information and if you are looking for it you can easily find it.

My main question is: how should the copyright text be put into the file?

- `<title>` element is for accessibility purposes, some user agents display the title element as a tooltip.
- `<desc>` element generally improves accessibility and you should describe what a user would see.
- ugly way: a text element with inline CSS to hide it. Don't even think about this! :)
- `<!--Copyright info here-->` could be also a simple solution.
- `<metadata>`: this would the best way but I did not find a detailed definition and which child elements could live inside. Also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/DOM/SVGMetadataElement gives a 404.
  Under https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#MetadataElement we can find more details. But is RDF really necessary?

I think a `<metadata>` element is the right place, but which child elements should be used and is just RDF the way to go?

Comment: I agree that `<metadata>` is where this kind of info should go. I think the XML Schema allows you to just use text inside this element without additinal markup, be it RDF or anything else. But for accessibility reasons, I think it's a good idea to use some standardized markup for making explicit that you are encoding copyright information.

Comment: "But is RDF really necessary?" -- Sounds like you think this would be a problem … why?

Comment: I don't think it is a problem to use RDF, but I think it is a little bit overruled for "just" a copyright info...
@unor, which RDF property should I use?

Comment: Do note that if unor's answer helped you, you can vote on it by clicking the arrows or accept it as correct by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the [`metadata` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/metadata.html#MetadataElement) is the correct choice here. It has to contain XML, but it doesn’t *have* to be a RDF serialization (e.g., [RDF/XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDF/XML)).

But I think it makes sense to use RDF here, because that’s exactly RDF’s job (providing metadata about resources, like SVG documents), and there is probably no other XML-based metadata language that has greater reach / better support.

A simple RDF statement (in RDF/XML) could look like this:

```xml
<metadata>
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/my-svg-file.svg">
      <schema:license rdf:resource="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/"/>
    </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
```

The `about` attribute [takes an IRI as value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884909/1591669); for a stand-alone SVG document, you could provide an empty value (= the base IRI of the document).

In this example I use the [`license` property from Schema.org](http://schema.org/license):

> A license document that applies to this content, typically indicated by URL.

(The vocabulary Schema.org is supported by several big search engines.)

Comment: Not sure if useful to you, but in SVG Tiny, [you can use RDFa attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23181532/1591669) on the SVG elements directly (i.e., not just as XHTML+RDFa inside of `metadata`).

Comment: How would I extend this with a list of the work's author(s)?

Comment: Having the same question as in the previous comment, I ended up looking how Inkscape stores author and license information in RDF tags (can be set in the document properties).